# Change button image after click to "loading" and then with another image after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, html

Been struggling all day with this, and I've got to the point where my code isn't working at all!
What I'm trying to do is:

When the user clicks `ImageButton1`, that image is replaced with another image `LoadingImg`, and then after 10 seconds, that image is replaced with another image/button `ImageButton2`

Here is my non-functional code:

```
<img src="images/xboxsite_14.gif" id="ImageButton1" onClick="showLoad()">
<img src="images/getld.png" id="ImageButton2" alt="Get Last Digits" style="display:none;">
<img src="images/Loader.gif" id="LoadingImg" style="display:none;">

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  

function showLoad() {
    document.getElementById('ImageButton1').src=document.getElementById('LoadingImg').src;
    document.getElementById('LoadingImg').style.display='block';
    setTimeout(swapImageSrc, 1000);
}​

function swapImageSrc() {
    document.getElementById('LoadingImg').src = document.getElementById('ImageButton2').src;
    document.getElementById('LoadingImg').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('ImageButton2').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('Code1String').style.display='block';
}

</script>
```

The only thing I can think of is that I changed the charset from 'charset=iso-8859-1' to 'charset=UTF-8' because I got a 'unsupported characters' error randomly (there are none).

If anyone can fix this then I will be extremely grateful, thanks!

Comment: When you say your code isn't working, what do you mean?  What errors do you see in your debugger?

Comment: The timeout is set to 1000, which is 1 second (and not 10)

Comment: @jmort253 - The whole thing, when the image 'ImageButton1' is pressed, nothing happens.

Comment: @Elvis - Yes, sorry I just set it to that for testing (instead of waiting 10sec each test).

Comment: Are there any errors shown in the console?

Comment: Nope - non at all. Just the code is non-functional.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is the changing of the charaset to UTF-8, because of 'unsupported characters', when they're none!

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up your logic..
http://jsfiddle.net/3ySkE/

```
function showLoad() {
    document.getElementById('ImageButton1').src = document.getElementById('LoadingImg').src;

    setTimeout(swapImageSrc, 1000);
}

function swapImageSrc() {
    document.getElementById('ImageButton1').src = document.getElementById('ImageButton2').src;

}​
```

Answer (score 0):

This works...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org      /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<script  language="javascript">  

function showLoad() {   

 document.getElementById('ImageButton1').src = '';
 document.getElementById('LoadingImg').src = 'images/Loader.gif';
 setTimeout(swapImageSrc, 10000);
}

function swapImageSrc() {
 document.getElementById('LoadingImg').src = '';    
 document.getElementById('ImageButton2').src = 'images/getld.png';
 document.getElementById('Code1String').style.display='block';
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<img src="images/xboxsite_14.gif" id="ImageButton1" onclick="showLoad()">
<img src="" id="ImageButton2">
<img src="" id="LoadingImg">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I try to save/compile the code, I get the error 'The documents current encoding cannot save all of the characters within the document' when there are absolutely no special characters. It is within the code above somewhere as well, because if i remove that code it 'saves' just fine.

Comment: I guess this happens because when you copy directly from here and save..the special character ` used for tagging code goes along and creates problem. Copy and paste in notepad. Then copy from notepad to your editor..If you spot unwanted tilde ` remove them. If the message comes ...go ahead and save. Did the code work for you?         I tested in firefox.

Comment: Got it working, C&P'ed the code to a new file (bug within dreamweaver -.-).

Comment: `<script  language="javascript">  

function showLoad() {   

 document.getElementById('ImageButton1').src = document.getElementById('LoadingImg').src;
 setTimeout(swapImageSrc, 10000);
}

function swapImageSrc() {
 document.getElementById('ImageButton1').src = document.getElementById('ImageButton2').src;
 document.getElementById('Code1String').style.display='block';
}

</script>`

Thats my code now, however, the 'ImageButton2' isn't a 'new button', its just the same 'Imagebutton1' with a new image source

Do you know of any way of making it a 'element/button' of its own?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong of course, but could it be that this is what you are after, a cleaner code might help you debug your issue:

```
<img src="images/xboxsite_14.gif" id="ImageButton1" onClick="action();">

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  

function action()
{
swapImage('images/getld.png') ;
window.setTimeout(function ()
{
swapImage('images/Loader.gif') 
}, 1000)
};


var swapImage = function(src)
{
    document.getElementById("ImageButton1").src = src;
}


</script>
```