# Change image in button on click

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a button with an image inside that I want to swap when clicked. I got that part working, but now I also want it to change back to the original image when clicked again.

The code I'm using:

```
<button onClick="action();">click me<img src="images/image1.png" width="16px" id="ImageButton1"></button>
```

And the Javascript:

```
function action() {
  swapImage('images/image2.png');
};

var swapImage = function(src) {
  document.getElementById("ImageButton1").src = src;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465082/change-button-image-after-click-to-loading-and-then-with-another-image-after-1?rq=1

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you *could* use a global variable, you don't need to. When you use setAttribute/getAttribute, you add something that appears as an attrib in the HTML. You also need to be aware that adding a global simply adds the variable to the window or the navigator or the document object (I don't remember which).

You can also add it to the object itself (i.e as a variable that isn't visible if the html is viewed, but is visible if you view the html element as an object in the debugger and look at it's properties.)

Here's two alternatives. 1 stores the alternative image in a way that will cause it to visible in the html, the other doesn't.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}

window.addEventListener('load', mInit, false);

function mInit()
{
    var tgt = byId('ImageButton1');
    tgt.secondSource = 'images/image2.png';
}

function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}

function action() 
{
    var tgt = byId('ImageButton1');
    var tmp = tgt.src;
    tgt.src = tgt.secondSource;
    tgt.secondSource = tmp;
};

function action2()
{
    var tgt = byId('imgBtn1');
    var tmp = tgt.src;
    tgt.src = tgt.getAttribute('src2');
    tgt.setAttribute('src2', tmp);
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <button onClick="action();">click me<img src="images/image1.png" width="16px" id="ImageButton1"></button>
    <br>
    <button onClick="action2();">click me<img id='imgBtn1' src="images/image1.png" src2='images/image2.png' width="16px"></button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the old value in a global variable.

For example:

```
var globalVarPreviousImgSrc;
var swapImage = function(src)
{
   var imgBut = document.getElementById("ImageButton1");

   globalVarPreviousImgSrc = imgBut.src;
   imgBut.src = src;
}
```

Then in the action method you can check if it was equal to the old value

```
function action()
{
  if(globalVarPreviousImgSrc != 'images/image2.png')
  {
    swapImage('images/image2.png');
  }else{
    swapImage(globalVarPreviousImgSrc);
  }
}
```

Comment: When I use this, the image changes the first time I click, but doesn't change back.

Answer (score 0):

Check this a working example just copy paste and run-

**HTML**

```
<button onClick="action();">click me<img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000000/fff.gif&text=Image+1" width="200px" id="ImageButton1"></button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
function action()
{
if(document.getElementById("ImageButton1").src == 'http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000000/fff.gif&text=Image+1' )
document.getElementById("ImageButton1").src = 'http://dummyimage.com/200x200/dec4ce/fff.gif&text=Image+2';
else
document.getElementById("ImageButton1").src = 'http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000000/fff.gif&text=Image+1';
}
</script>
```

Check this **working** example - http://jsfiddle.net/QVRUG/4/

Comment: I'm unable to make it work. I've put it in a jsfiddle, it doesn't work there as well. http://jsfiddle.net/LqTGJ/

Comment: @JamesM please chk the updated fiddle, and let me know if u have any issues

Comment: The image also doesn't change in that one I think.

Comment: @JamesM really ?? Its working fine at my end check once more -->  http://jsfiddle.net/QVRUG/1/

Comment: @JamesM Look at the text its changing

Comment: @JamesM look i updated with a new image http://jsfiddle.net/QVRUG/4/ let me know your case now

Comment: That's so weird, I tried it with Chrome and IE and the text stays the same?

Comment: @JamesM try in your local html file and let me know the case as I am also using chrome this time

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to use global variables in javascripts use a closure or object literal. You can do something like using a closure

```
(function(){
  var clickCounter = 0;
  var imgSrc1 = "src to first image";
  var imgSrc2 = "src to second image"
  functions swapImage (src)
  {
   var imgBut = document.getElementById("ImageButton1");
   imgBut.src = src;
  }

  function action()
  {
  if(clickCounter === 1)
  {
    swapImage(imgSrc1);
    --clickCounter;
  }else{
    swapImage(imgSrc2);
    ++clickCounter;
  }
}
})();
```

(I haven't run this code though)

This nice [w3documentation](http://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices#Avoid_globals) gives you best practices.